# Parse json returned from node server Spotify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, spotify

I want to send back properly formatted JSON from a node server to the front end.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/route', function(req, res){
    res.json(tracks)
});
```

Then in the front end, I am making a `GET` request using jQuery

```
$.get('http://localhost:8888/route', function(data){
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

This is returning the data, however, it is returning it as a string. I have tried to use `JSON.parse` but am getting the following error message. `data` on the node side is an array of objects. Perhaps this is causing an issue.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2847(…)

To fill the tracks array I have the following code

```
tracks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < songLinks.length; i++) {
  request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/' + songLinks[i].split(":").pop(), function(error, response, body) {
    tracks.push(body)
  });
}
```

The first item in the array of tracks is:

> "{↵  "album" : {↵    "album_type" : "album",↵    "artists" : [ {↵
>   "external_urls" : {↵        "spotify" :
>   "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT"↵      },↵
>   "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT",↵
>   "id" : "1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT",↵      "name" : "Modest Mouse",↵
>   "type" : "artist",↵      "uri" :
>   "spotify:artist:1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT"↵    } ],↵
>   "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO",
>   "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO",
>   "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU",
>   "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT",
>   "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT",
>   "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],↵
>   "external_urls" : {↵      "spotify" :
>   "https://open.spotify.com/album/4YvdAtWh6LlnIrv0qIqkCF"↵    },↵
>   "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4YvdAtWh6LlnIrv0qIqkCF",↵ 
>   "id" : "4YvdAtWh6LlnIrv0qIqkCF",↵    "images" : [ {↵      "height" :
>   640,↵      "url" :
>   "https://i.scdn.co/image/411d254a0e46f509dda22f58d699782f16f7bd44",↵
>   "width" : 640↵    }, {↵      "height" : 300,↵      "url" :
>   "https://i.scdn.co/image/982b3b7c3ad3e81aed9e0475da07894262f93923",↵
>   "width" : 300↵    }, {↵      "height" : 64,↵      "url" :
>   "https://i.scdn.co/image/e4a25681c1163b349ff71b464d2cfc8fda089d58",↵
>   "width" : 64↵    } ],↵    "name" : "No One's First, And You're Next",↵
>   "type" : "album",↵    "uri" : "spotify:album:4YvdAtWh6LlnIrv0qIqkCF"↵ 
>   },↵  "artists" : [ {↵    "external_urls" : {↵      "spotify" :
>   "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT"↵    },↵
>   "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT",↵
>   "id" : "1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT",↵    "name" : "Modest Mouse",↵
>   "type" : "artist",↵    "uri" :
>   "spotify:artist:1yAwtBaoHLEDWAnWR87hBT"↵  } ],↵  "available_markets" :
>   [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL",
>   "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI",
>   "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT",
>   "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL",
>   "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK",
>   "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],↵  "disc_number" : 1,↵  "duration_ms" :
>   330573,↵  "explicit" : false,↵  "external_ids" : {↵    "isrc" :
>   "USSM10700655"↵  },↵  "external_urls" : {↵    "spotify" :
>   "https://open.spotify.com/track/6Z3pIqEp5n5faSopwto0tB"↵  },↵  "href"
>   : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6Z3pIqEp5n5faSopwto0tB",↵  "id" :
>   "6Z3pIqEp5n5faSopwto0tB",↵  "name" : "King Rat",↵  "popularity" : 38,↵
>   "preview_url" :
>   "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/037294fdd97c94bebf14e7ec1b1fb2c0a1986adc",↵
>   "track_number" : 7,↵  "type" : "track",↵  "uri" :
>   "spotify:track:6Z3pIqEp5n5faSopwto0tB"↵}"

Below is a screenshot of the response also in case it will make my question any clearer.

[image]

Comment: It means `data` is not a valid `json`

Comment: @Rayon thanks! am i doing something wrong on the node side?

Comment: Could you post the code how you create the data on the node.js side? Could you also post one json string(index 0 in the screenshot)?

Comment: @phantom You can validate your json here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @MartinGottweis see updated question

Comment: @Michelangelo it tells me that it is valid json

Comment: Suggest you just log the data received (rather than the result of the parse): this will allow you to copy it into other tools (or examine it manually)

Comment: provide the code that generates `tracks`

Comment: @madalinivascu I have -- see updated question

Comment: It looks like you have JSON inside JSON. You should parse spotify response body before pushing it to `tracks` array.

Comment: @ErykNapierała this worked!

Comment: @phantom glad to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the body to response

```
request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/' + songLinks[i].split(":").pop(), function(error, response, body) {
    tracks.push(JSON.parse(body));
  });
```

Comment: this gives me an array of objects,  and kind of works. It means on the front end i have to loop through each object returned and `JSON.parse(data[i].body)`. Is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: the issue was i didn't parse the response body before pushing to the tracks array.

Comment: yes if you have valid json you don't need to parse each item

Comment: i suggest you use https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-tracks/ to get multiple traks ,its a single ajax call